# @return int always return string php

Tags: php, function, apache2

I have the next piece of code:

```
 /**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

When I  execute into a server with **apache2**, this return always string value, but in an another server with **nginx** return integer value. 
Why is the difference here, the configuration into nginx or apache or php.ini?

I have php7 in both servers.

Please, I need to know why occur this issue. Thanks for reply.

Comment: `$this->id` is either an integer or a string when it is set, that return just returns it.  If you always need an integer then `return (int)$this->id;`.  This `@return int` is just a comment for documentation.

Comment: But the problem is, why occur in different environments?

Comment: You would need to find where `$this->id` is set and where does that value come from?

Comment: just a guess but most likely  your database schema, nginx/apache make no difference as it's the php interpreter that is doing the work, so something in your environment must be different.

Comment: Yes, because in a development stage I have mySQL and production SQL Server, maybe this could be the problem in a return values. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP comments usually have no impact on run time. There are special cases with comments being used in code, but type hinting isn't usually one of them. It's just for humans and IDEs to provide information about type.

So the *reason* it's different is because wherever that value is coming from makes it different.

You can *cast*, as in convert, the value to a necessary type explicitly `return (int) $this->id`.

Since PHP 7 it *does* allow you to explicitly specify return type:

```php
public function getId() : int
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

See [return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) in documentation for details.

Comment: for casting i presume it's better to use `return intval($this->id);`

Comment: `intval()` is a number base conversion function, it does more and has overhead of a function call. If you want specifically to cast to a type and just that then casting (e.g. `(int)`) is intended and appropriate way.